# Clicking on certain extension links in admin menu causes 302 redirect to dashboard

Tags: admin, redirect

Whenever I click on certain extension links in Magento admin the page redirects to the Magento dashboard. Nothing is showing up in the system or exception logs.

I cannot access the extension pages or config. It's happening for M2E Pro and some other plugins.

Comment: The issue was related to caching. I turned off Varnish related caching from the Magento admin caching page and I am now able to access the menus.

Comment: It wouldn't let me at the time saying I had to wait 8 hours... I'll try it again now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related to caching. I turned off Varnish related caching from the Magento admin caching page and I am now able to access the menus.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that all files of your extension is uploaded correctly.

and comment the `var folder` on root and create new var folder. 
Your extension will work correctly.

Comment: The problem was related to the caching system - thank you anyway :-)